# Referencing a property in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

Is it possible to reference properties in an AppleScript?

I’m writing some code for QLab (Sound, video and lighting control for macOS) and I’d like to be able to have a certain property defined/selected/referenced in the first part of the code and then recalled later. I'm looking to reference one kind of property and then be able to reference an other property without having to duplicate my code and changing out that part.

[QLab's AppleScript Dictionary can be found here](https://qlab.app/docs/v4/scripting/applescript-dictionary-v4/#cue)

So my example of something that works without a reference is this:

```
tell application id "com.figure53.QLab.4" to tell front workspace
    set selectedCues to last item of (selected as list) -- selects an item in my software (QLab)
    return q name of selectedCues -- This works and returns q name of selectedCues
end tell
```

I'd like to do the same, but reference the property "q name" and call for it later

In my script I've tried various versions of setting a variable (selected Property) to q name

```
tell application id "com.figure53.QLab.4" to tell front workspace
    set selectedCues to last item of (selected as list) -- selects an item in my software (QLab)
    set selectedProperty to q name -- This code doesn't work
    return selectedProperty of selectedCues -- This is broken
end tell
```

***EDIT: Added new examples to better explain what I'm looking for:***

I've written a script here that with a handler that returns a selected property of selectedCues (items in my software). It lets the user pick from a list and then with if statements grabs the values selected in the dialog:

```
tell application id "com.figure53.QLab.4" to tell front workspace
    
    set selectedCues to (selected as list)
    
    set parameterChoices to {"q name", "q number", "q type", "q color", "notes"}
    
    choose from list parameterChoices with prompt "Pick a property to return from selected cue" with title "Choose a property" default items {"q Name"}
    
    set selectedProperty to item 1 of result
    
end tell

returnPropertyOfSelected(selectedProperty, selectedCues)

on returnPropertyOfSelected(cueProperty, cuesToProcess)
    
    tell application id "com.figure53.QLab.4" to tell front workspace
        
        set returnedValue to {}
        
        if cueProperty is "q name" then -- Using if statements here to make returnedValue return selected property
            repeat with i in cuesToProcess
                set end of returnedValue to (q name of i)
            end repeat
        else if cueProperty is "q number" then
            repeat with i in cuesToProcess
                set end of returnedValue to (q number of i)
            end repeat
        else if cueProperty is "q type" then
            repeat with i in cuesToProcess
                set end of returnedValue to (q type of i)
            end repeat
        else if cueProperty is "q color" then
            repeat with i in cuesToProcess
                set end of returnedValue to (q color of i)
            end repeat
        else if cueProperty is "notes" then
            repeat with i in cuesToProcess
                set end of returnedValue to (notes of i)
            end repeat
        end if
        
        returnedValue
        
    end tell
    
end returnPropertyOfSelected
```

Doing it this way I have to make an if statement for every choice  the user could make. I'm wondering if there is a way to have this selection referenced and implemented directly into the code so I wont have to make an if statement for every choice possible.

Optimally I'd like something like this:

```
tell application id "com.figure53.QLab.4" to tell front workspace
    
    set selectedCues to (selected as list)
    
    set parameterChoices to {"q name", "q number", "q type", "q color", "notes"}
    
    choose from list parameterChoices with prompt "Pick a property to return from selected cue" with title "Choose a property" default items {"q Name"}
    
    set selectedProperty to item 1 of result
    
end tell

returnPropertyOfSelected(selectedProperty, selectedCues)

on returnPropertyOfSelected(cueProperty, cuesToProcess)
    
    tell application id "com.figure53.QLab.4" to tell front workspace
        
        set returnedValue to {}
        
        repeat with i in cuesToProcess
            set end of returnedValue to (cueProperty of i) -- This is the part I would like, but it doesn't work
        end repeat
        
        returnedValue
        
    end tell
    
end returnPropertyOfSelected
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [Variables and Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_variables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH223-SW10) in the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1).

Comment: Been looking a this for quite a while now, but thanks for the reference anyway. I don't seem to find a solution that works. Not sure if I'm doing it wrong, it's simply not possible or there's a workaround.

Comment: Been trying:
`set selectedProperty to a reference to q name`
but it doesn't seem to work. I'm quite new to AppleScript, so I might very well be missing something here.

Comment: No - If I am understanding correctly, `q name` would be a scripting term of QLab.  A property (or variable) can hold a _value_, but a scripting term like that is essentially  a _command_ to the app.

Comment: And there is no way of referencing this _command_?

In the Script Editor library it's listed like a type: property (of an item), just like a "name" would be of "An item" (a file) in Finder. Essentially what I'm looking for is being able to change the code in one place and having it reflected in the rest of the code.

Comment: Any given application scripting term is only valid within a tell statement targeting that application, otherwise the term has no special meaning.  You can do something like put the application tell statement in a handler, and use arguments (string, number, enumeration, etc) for an if statement.

Comment: But if I made handlers I would then need one for every property to handle. Is that correctly understood? If so I can't have one handler using a variable/reference for a term set earlier, but I'd have to make several copies of handlers with only the term changed?

Comment: You can use a common handler, and compare your arguments in an if statement to determine the statement to perform, for example `if argument is "qname" then return q name of selectedCues`.  Another option would be to create a command string to use in a `run script` command.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do, and I think you are a bit confused about how programming/AppleScript works. I suggest you post a longer example of working code so we understand what your program needs to do; you can then ask if there’s a more compact way to do it.

Comment: @foo I've now edited my post and added new examples trying to explain what I'm looking to do. Hope this clears up some of the confusion.

Comment: Honestly, the only change I’d make is to use a single `repeat` loop outside the `if` statement, simplifying the code. What you want to do—look up record properties using strings as property keys—is not something AS is designed to do. (It‘s trivial in scripting languages such as Python and JavaScript, which use dynamic hash objects instead of static structs, but their Apple event bridges are either unsupported or don’t work worth a damn.) While it’s possible to hack dynamic property lookups in AppleScript, such hackery is hardly conducive to simple, reliable scripts. KISS, and move along.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I totally get it now and I've learned a lot. I'll probably stick to repeat loops and if statements, but I now have a vastly better understanding of why to do so. I've already been able to remove a lot of unnecessary code by using the `if argument is "qname" then return q name of selectedCues` provided by @red_menace. Combined with changing it to use a single repeat loop cuts down the coding time by A LOT. Originally I had individual  handlers for every single choice the user could make, which felt so inefficient and was why I started looking into all of this.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with what I think you are trying to do, is that outside of an application tell statement, any given application's scripting terms have no special meaning.  One way to use arbitrary scripting terms at run time would be to use the `run script` command, since it can use text passed to it as a separate script to run.

Note that this is usually considered a Bad Idea™, especially since trying to use a common handler and passing terms to it most often winds up longer than just using separate commands.  You can also usually get a record of *all* an item's properties, which is also easier than using separate commands.  But if you think you need to do stuff like this, you should always verify the terms you plan on using and not allow the user to enter terms (or if you must also do that, make sure you sanitize them).

I don't have the **QLab** application used in your post, so the following example uses **System Events** and a couple of different methods to get the property of a file item.  One way uses a handler that creates a script using a pre-defined term, and the other gets the value from a record of the item properties :

```
property itemClass : "class"
property itemType : "type identifier" -- UTI
property itemName : "name"
property itemDefault : "default application" -- alias

set fileItem to (choose file)

log runScript(itemType, fileItem) -- get property by creating a script using a term

tell application "System Events" to set itemProperties to (get properties of disk item (fileItem as text))
log type identifier of itemProperties -- get property from a record of all the properties

to runScript(fileProperty, fileItem) -- get specified file property
   return run script "tell application \"System Events\" to return " & fileProperty & " of disk item " & space & quote & fileItem & quote
end runScript
```

Comment: this seems to be kind of what I'm looking for yea. I understand that it's generally not a good idea to do this, but I was wondering if it was worth it to optimise code and if I'm doing stuff inefficient. I've added new examples to my post, that hopefully explains what I'm looking to do a little better. Your solution here seems like it could be integrated, but I also see why it wouldn't really be advised.

Comment: A fundamental thing that I'm starting to understand now is that I might be using the word "property" wrong. I get that AppleScripts can contain properties and those can be defined in the script. What I'm looking to reference is probably what you call a "term" for my software. But when I in Script Editor opened the Library for QLab, it lists the term  "q name" as a Type: Property (of an Element (a cue))

Comment: "cue n : A cue.
elements
contains cues; contained by workspaces, cues.
properties
q name (text) : The name of the cue. Not unique."

Comment: @baldrian-sector - Can you get _all_ the properties of a cue?

Comment: Yes I can! 

`tell application id "com.figure53.QLab.4" to tell front workspace
 set selectedCues to last item of (selected as list)
 get properties of selectedCues
end tell`

does the trick and gets all properties

Comment: @baldrian-sector - Excellent.  Once you get a record with all the properties, then you can just get a value from the desired key without having to use any scripting terms, such as what I did in my example .  Of course, regular AppleScript can’t use dynamic record keys either, but it is fairly easy using some Cocoa via AppleScriptObjC.

Comment: @red_menace: While it is true that ASOC bridges AS records to Cocoa’s `NSDictionary`, which typically accepts strings as keys, that won’t work here as only properties with user-defined identifiers are bridged; any properties with keyword-based keys (which is what scriptable apps return) are discarded. Plus, ASOC will mangle/reject any properties that contain application references.

Answer (score 1):

For sake of completeness only[1], here is how you do property lookups in AppleScript using strings as keys:

```
to makePropertyAccessor(appName, propertyName)
    (*
       WARNING: this handler does not sanitize its inputs. 
       NEVER call from untrusted code. Severe risk of data 
       destruction from accidental errors/injection attacks.
    *)
    run script "script
        to getProperty(inObject)
            tell application \"" & appName & "\"
                return " & propertyName & " of inObject
            end tell
        end getProperty
        
        to setProperty(inObject, newValue)
            tell application \"" & appName & "\"
                set " & propertyName & " of inObject to newValue
            end tell
        end setProperty
    end script"
end makePropertyAccessor


-- example usage:

set ContainerAccessor to makePropertyAccessor("Finder", "container")

tell application "Finder" to set aRecord to properties of home

ContainerAccessor's getProperty(aRecord)
--> folder "Users" of startup disk of application "Finder"
```

Like most code generation, this is totally evil and unsafe, and stands excellent chance of doing serious damage should you [screw up](https://xkcd.com/327/). While I appreciate that typing out a lengthy `if` block is somewhat tedious, such code is simple, clear, reliable, and about as idiot-proof as it gets. And AppleScript is already janky enough without any “clever hacks” on top. KISS.

--

[1] I wouldn’t post it at all except that @red_menace’s implementation is problematic in that 1. it is totally insecure which it fails to mention, and 2. it jumps across different interpreter contexts to do the work so is slow and cannot pass references and other complex values in and out without wrecking them. This does not mean mine is without problems: aside from also being totally insecure, I vaguely recall `run script` would leak memory on each call. However, it only has to be called once for each property you want to access, and the reusable object returned executes in the current context so there are no problems with passing values in and out of its handlers.